# Android: how to send UDP packet using thread or asynctask

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm writing a simple chat application on android using UDP. I have a thread (inner class) that is used for receiving packets. fSocket listens to port 11200 for packets.

```
private class fThread extends Thread {
    private int LISTENING_PORT = 11200;
    DatagramSocket fSocket;
    DatagramPacket fpacket;

    public fThread() {
        try {
                 fSocket= new DatagramSocket(LISTENING_PORT); 
                 fSocket.setBroadcast(false);
            }catch (IOException e) {}
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
                 while (true) {
                     byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                     fpacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length); 
                     fSocket.receive(fpacket);
                     //some other code below
                 }
            }
    }
        private void Write(byte[] newfpacket,String DestIP1) {
   try {
        String data = new String (newfpacket);
            DatagramPacket toForward = new DatagramPacket(data.getBytes(),data.length(),InetAddress.getByName(DestIP1.trim()), LISTENING_PORT);
                uniSocket.setBroadcast(false);
                uniSocket.send(toForward);
                catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                android.util.Log.i(TAG1,"Unknown host exception:"+e1.getMessage());
                e1.printStackTrace();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                android.util.Log.i(TAG1,"Some IO exception: "+e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

When I click a button, I call the 
fThread fthread = new fThread();
fthread.Write(somemessage,"192.168.1.105"), I get a networkonmainthread exception I know
it is because the write is being done on main thread, and has to be a Thread of its own or AsyncTAsk. 
Basically I want to send a UDP packet when ever I press a button, to LISTENING_PORT at some destIP. I try to do it like this, but not sure how to progress to make the thread send a single packet whenever I click a button.

```
 private class sendThread extends Thread { //for sending packet to listening port
     DatagramSocket uniSocket;

     void run (){

     }
 }
```

Comment: You can't just call arbitrary methods in a Thread and have them run *on* the thread.  You will probably find it easier to use an AsyncTask or handler for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is to use a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Object>`. In the `Thread` or `AsynTask` you need to check if that queue has something to be sent in which case you remove it (poll) from the queue and send it. In the main thread when a button is clicked you just create the object and put it in the queue `queue.add()` , this way you won't receive the exception. The `object` is just a class where you keep the data (bytes) to be sent, also, along with the data, you may keep the destination IP address, Port number, etc. See the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` manual for the methods you have in order to `add` and `poll` the objects. I have working examples in case you need it, is for TCP though the idea is applicable for your case.

You need to launch the AyncTask or Thread at startup, this thread or asyntask sleeps `Thread.sleep(250)` for example, while the queue is empty. When you got something to send `poll` it from the queue and send it.

EDIT (exmaples):

```
// this is the class used to send the packets (data)
public class QueueItem
{
    private static final String defaultIP = "192.168.1.150";
    private static final short defaultPort = 3030;
    public byte[] data = null;
    public String dstIP;
    public short dstPort;

    public QueueItem(byte[] theData) {
        this(theData, "", 0);
    }

    public QueueItem(byte[] theData, String theIP) {
        this(theData, theIP, 0);
    }

    public QueueItem(byte[] theData, String theIP, int thePort) {
        this.data = null;
        if (theData != null && theData.length > 0)
        {
            data = new byte[theData.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < theData.length; i++)
                this.data[i] = theData[i];
        }
        if (theIP.trim().length() > 0) this.dstIP = theIP.trim();
        else this.dstIP = defaultIP; // for example
        if (thePort != 0) this.dstPort = (short) thePort;
        else this.dstPort = defaultPort; // for example
    }
}
```

```
// To declare the Queue
public static final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<QueueItem> myQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<QueueItem>();
public static boolean Terminated=false;

// To queue something do like this:
    QueueItem qItem = new QueueItem("This is a test message".getBytes());
    myQueue.add(qItem);
```

```
// in the doInBackground of your AsyncTask
while (!Terminated) 
{
    while (!Terminated && myQueue.isEmpty()) 
    { 
        Thread.sleep(250);
    }
    if (Terminated) break;
    QueueItem qItem = myQueue.poll();
    if (qItem != null)
    {
        DatagramPacket toForward = new DatagramPacket(qItem.data, qItem.data.length,InetAddress.getByName(qItem.dstIP, qItem.dstPort));
        uniSocket.setBroadcast(false);
        uniSocket.send(toForward);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can I see how you implemented it, also what happens if you try to poll queue when its empty

Comment: If you try to poll when it's empty you'll get a null object. See my edited question for an example.